# change default group to specific group while sharing to yammer from wordpress

Tags: yammer

Hi i am using yammer share button in my wordpress site everything working is fine.
but whenever i will share by default it will share to All Company group, i want to remove all Company group, please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I do have same issue, any updates on this ?